# How do you divide a property with linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

imagine I got an entity:

```
MyEntity
{
...
Nullable<Int64> MyProperty
...
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
Ctx.MyEntity.Where(x=>x.MyProperty/16 == 10)
```

with Linq.Expression

So I create a parameter:

```
var param = Expression.parameter(typeOf(MyEntity));
```

Then the property:

```
var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param,"MyProperty");
```

If I would like to compare to 10 I would have done something like this:

```
var cmp = Expression.equal(prop,Expression.constant(10,prop.Type));
```

But first I need to divide prop by 16.

So I try:

```
var div = Expression.Divide(prop,Expression.constant(16, prop.type);
```

And this throw an exception of unmatching type.

Can someone help ?

Thx,

Comment: Guess: You need to access the .Value of that Nullable. Perhaps the compiler does that for you in the "something like this" code.  Another idea, provide the Int64 type in the divide expression creation (not the Nullable!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create division expression like this:

```
Expression.Divide(prop, Expression.Constant((Nullable<Int64>)16, prop.Type))
```

It is necessary to explicitly convert 16 to type of the property, since when used as a literal, it is of type `Int32`, which is obviously not same as `Nullable<Int64>`.

Comment: You rocks !Something strange is that if I write Expression.Constant((Nullable<Int64>)16) it creates a constant with type Int64. Do you maybee know why ?

Comment: @Pit Ming Hm, that's interesting. I can only assume that when casting numbers like this, there is some optimization being done either by compiler (unlikely) or when casting. But I am not really sure - perhaps create a separate question for that.

Comment: @PitMing there's no such thing as a constant nullable.  For example, you can't declare `const long? x = 16L;`  Why don't you get a type error when you pass the nullable value?  Because there's no such thing as a boxed nullable; when you box a `Nullable<T>`, the result is a boxed `T`.  So the logic in the `Constant` method cannot distinguish between your having passed a `Nullable<Int64>` and a plain old `Int64`.

Comment: Lotar, following from my previous comment, this would work, too: `Expression.Divide(prop, Expression.Constant(16L, prop.Type))`